# difference among "could","can","would","will" in meaning

Tags: modal-verbs

> If you know football really well, then you **could/can/would/will** probably explain it to a non-fan.

source:http://marker.to/GwLeLi

Comment: I think this is actually a good question.

Comment: This is a good and canonical-like question. I'd like to see it remain open.

Answer (score 5):

(Native American English speaker)

I like Omni's answer, I am only adding onto it.

I want to offer an example where "**could**" and "**can**" can't be interchanged.

> I'm so hungry I could eat a horse.

This is an idiom. I am **very** hungry, to the point where *if I wanted to* I could eat an entire horse. However "I'm so hungry I can eat a horse" sounds wrong and "I can eat a horse" would mean something entirely different. If you are so hungry that you **could** eat a horse, you aren't meaning this literally. If you say you **can** eat a horse, you mean that you literally are capable of eating a horse. **Could**'s emphasis is on intent where **can**'s emphasis is on ability. "I **could** eat a horse" means that you're hungry. "I **can** eat a horse" means that you have an extremely large stomach.

Here's an example where would and will can't be interchanged.

> If I were you, I would go to the doctor.

I can't possibly be you and go to the doctor. In this hypothetical situation where I am you, I **would** go. But I can't possibly be you, so "will" doesn't make sense. Will means that I am going to, there is no hypothetical situations.

"If my condition gets worse, I will go to the doctor" is okay because it is a definite, expected thing to do.

Here's an example where would and could can't be interchanged.

> If I won a million dollars I could buy a Ferrari.

That doesn't mean I necessarily am going to buy a Ferrari, it's just an option. If I said "If I won a million dollars I would buy a Ferrari", I mean that I necessarily am going to buy a Ferrari. I *will* buy a Ferrari.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question:

- ***could***: have the potential, if so inclined
- ***can***: have the potential, without regard to your inclinations
- ***would***: have the potential, and (the speaker believes) are likely to do so
- ***will***: at some point in the future this shall occur

Comment: might want to say "almost certainly" instead of "shall", because I don't think learners will pick up the nuance of "shall". And "shall" is pretty much identical to "will" anyways.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi Thank you. You are talking the difference between "have the potential" and "at some point in the future this shall occur", right?