# Is the sentence "A and B are interchanged" grammatically correct or not?

Tags: grammar

An answerer [gives an example](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/76258/109190)

> If I won a million dollars I could buy a Ferrari.

and explains

> "would" and "could" **can't be interchanged**. That doesn't mean I necessarily am going to buy a Ferrari, it's just an option. If I said "If I won a million dollars I would buy a Ferrari", I mean that I necessarily am going to buy a Ferrari. I *will* buy a Ferrari.

I could have said

> If "would" and "could" are interchanged, the meaning changes ...

or

> If "would" and "could" are interchanged with each other, the meaning changes ...

The last 2 sentences are my own version. I am concerned with whether the first is grammatical. If it is, is the second a bit wordy?

In other words, is "with each other" required, optional or unnecessary in this context?

---

Not important but necessary:

I've looked that up on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interchange) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interchange) and didn't got an answer.

Comment: Questions about answers... In the subjunctive, when you say "If ... I **could** buy X" it means "able to buy": can...could. When you say "If ... I **would** buy X" it means "intend to buy": will...would. The words **could** and **would** are both OK but they mean different things because they come from different verbs.

Comment: @WeatherVane Are you asking some questions to me or just make some supplement to my OP?

Comment: I misunderstood the complicated question. The phrase "with each other" is unnecessary, because that is what "interchanged" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct (*it's just passive voice*).  The sentence:

"If "would" and "could" are interchanged, the meaning changes."

is just the passive voice equivalent of:

"If I interchange "would" and "could", the meaning changes."

where most generic personal pronouns could be used depending on context.

**EDIT1:**

"interchanged"

and

"interchanged with each other"

both yield grammatically correct sentences.  Furthermore you can safely drop the extra verbiage without losing information or confusing the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you noticed the question "In other words, is "with each other" required, optional or unnecessary in this context" in my OP?

Comment: @WXJ96163  See my **EDIT1**